# IOS Hybrid App and DFP Aysnronous Ads

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, webview, hybrid-mobile-app, google-dfp

We have launched a hybrid app in the Apple store and and we load the webview live from the server.  All of our requests go through the http:// or https:// protocol, and are loaded in a standard webview component.

We still have the same ads from our webview there as they are within content

One issue we are having is if a user has the keyboad open before the ad loads, that when the ad loads it is killing the IOS app keyboard.

Have you encountered this?

Thanks the app is https://itunes.apple.com/CA/app/id994745056?mt=8

Greatly appreciated.

Comment: (killing the IOS app keyboard)?? you mean it closes the Keyboard?? or kills it and dosen''t open again??  clarify the steps to your problem and put some code in your question to have look.

Comment: Hey, Sorry it is crashing the IOS keybaord.  The basic flow is: 1. Open page 2. open text box and start typing (before ads loads) 3  the ads loads and crashes the keyboard and it closes and loses focus. So the user has to re open the keyboard to continue. It happens with any text box with the app.  We are not seeing it in the webview as it users a slightly different keyboard than the  app.

Comment: try putting (e.preventDefault()) when you focus on the input boxes  -- http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: Thanks ill try that!